# Snap apps are not starting

Tags: snap

I am using many snap apps and most of those are not working, here is a message when i try to open a snap app from terminal

```
$ chromium
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/hrishikesh/snap/chromium/494/snap/chromium/494/Documents': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/hrishikesh/snap/chromium/494/snap/chromium/494/Desktop': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/hrishikesh/snap/chromium/494/snap/chromium/494/Downloads': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/hrishikesh/snap/chromium/494/snap/chromium/494/Music': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/hrishikesh/snap/chromium/494/snap/chromium/494/Pictures': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/hrishikesh/snap/chromium/494/snap/chromium/494/Videos': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/hrishikesh/snap/chromium/494/snap/chromium/494/Public': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/hrishikesh/snap/chromium/494/snap/chromium/494/Templates': No such file or directory
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

when I try to run with superuser the same problem occurs with a message

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
```

Comment: I have the same problem. The app folders in the snap directory are all empty.

Comment: most likely a software update has unset your JAVA_HOME, try to reset JAVA_HOME using export command in terminal.

Comment: Which is the relationship between the Snap issue and JAVA_HOME variable?

Comment: I had that problem yesterday and solved it that way. Might not be the solution for hrishikesh umralia, but worked for me. The next post explains how to set JAVA_HOME askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java I hope it helps.